# How to change php config in php.ini & post_max_size in laravel vapor? I'm facing error 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, laravel-vapor

How to changes php config & post_max_size setting in laravel vapor?

I'm facing error 413 Request Entity Too Large when trying to upload image on AWS S3.

Application is using Angular as frontend & Laravel is used for backend API.

I'm able to upload image size upto 200-250 KB on AWS-S3 but can't able to upload even 1MB file. Also, there is no validation error on backend API side.

As it is serverless. So, I'm not able to find the setting for php.ini and related settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the php variables using Docker runtime

> Docker Runtimes Docker based runtimes allow you to package and deploy
> applications up to 10GB in size and allow you to install additional
> PHP extensions or libraries by updating the environment's
> corresponding .Dockerfile. For every new Docker based environment,
> Vapor adds a .Dockerfile file that uses one of Vapor's base images as
> a starting point for building your image. All of Vapor's Docker images
> are based on Alpine Linux:

https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#runtime

```
# Update the `php.ini` file...
# Requires a `php.ini` file at the root of your project...
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/overrides.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Request Entity Too Large errors with Vapor usually means that Lambda isn't able to handle uploads of that size. I would expect the upper limit to be a bit higher than the 1MB you're reporting, but generally I go straight to uploading images/files directly to S3 from the front end no matter the size to avoid this cropping up.

There is a frontend package provided by the Vapor team that can help with this, which can be installed with `npm i -D laravel-vapor`.

More information on the package here: https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/resources/storage.html#installing-the-vapor-npm-package

And more information on file uploads to Laravel Vapor from the docs here:

> Due to AWS Lambda limitations, file uploads made directly to your application backend can only be up to roughly 4.5MB in size. This is a hard limit imposed by AWS, and updating the php.ini configuration file or any other configuration will not raise this limit. Therefore, to ensure your application's users won't receive an HTTP 413 Payload Too Large response, you may validate the file upload size using JavaScript before initiating the file upload to your application's backend.

> If your application needs to receive file uploads larger than AWS allows, those files must be streamed directly to S3 from your application's frontend (Browser). To assist you, we've written an NPM package that makes it easy to perform file uploads directly from your application's frontend.

https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/resources/storage.html#file-uploads